# Programmatically To check dll exists in Gac or not.If so display it in grid

Tags: c#

I will  have a list of dll's in a folder,  I want to check a dll for a application exists or not. If so i want to add that application name in grid.Can any one tell how to do it programmatically. Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you have a list of DLLs in a folder, it is very unlikely that folder happens to be part of the GAC.

Comment: Very closely releated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933947/check-gac-for-an-assembly

Comment: And also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456547/how-to-programmatically-determine-if-net-assembly-is-installed-in-gac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically determine if .NET assembly is installed in GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456547/how-to-programmatically-determine-if-net-assembly-is-installed-in-gac)

Answer (score 15):

Do an assembly.LoadFrom and check GlobalAssemblyCache

```
testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllname);

if (!testAssembly.GlobalAssemblyCache)
{
  // not in gac
}
```

Comment: I see no reason for a downvote. To me, this seems like the most elegant answer so far, since it doesn't require complex stuff with Fusion/COM. This should also work if you're loading assemblies in the [reflection-only context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

I think the proper way is Fusion COM API.

Here how to use it :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace IsAssemblyInGAC
{
    internal class GacApi
    {
        [DllImport("fusion.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateAssemblyCache(
            out IAssemblyCache ppAsmCache, int reserved);
    }

    // GAC Interfaces - IAssemblyCache. As a sample, non used vtable entries     
    [ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
    Guid("e707dcde-d1cd-11d2-bab9-00c04f8eceae")]
    internal interface IAssemblyCache
    {
        int Dummy1();
        [PreserveSig()]
        IntPtr QueryAssemblyInfo(
            int flags,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            String assemblyName,
            ref ASSEMBLY_INFO assemblyInfo);

        int Dummy2();
        int Dummy3();
        int Dummy4();
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct ASSEMBLY_INFO
    {
        public int cbAssemblyInfo;
        public int assemblyFlags;
        public long assemblySizeInKB;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public String currentAssemblyPath;

        public int cchBuf;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(QueryAssemblyInfo("System"));
            }
            catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        // If assemblyName is not fully qualified, a random matching may be 
        public static String QueryAssemblyInfo(String assemblyName)
        {
            ASSEMBLY_INFO assembyInfo = new ASSEMBLY_INFO ();
            assembyInfo.cchBuf = 512;
            assembyInfo.currentAssemblyPath = new String('\0', 
                assembyInfo.cchBuf) ;

            IAssemblyCache assemblyCache = null;

            // Get IAssemblyCache pointer
            IntPtr hr = GacApi.CreateAssemblyCache(out assemblyCache, 0);
            if (hr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                hr = assemblyCache.QueryAssemblyInfo(1, assemblyName, ref assembyInfo);
                if (hr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr.ToInt32());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr.ToInt32());
            }
            return assembyInfo.currentAssemblyPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Use `QueryAssemblyInfo` method.

Comment: HRESULT is defined as a 32 bit integer, so CreateAssemblyCache and QueryAssemblyInfo should return int rather than IntPtr.

Comment: What are the `Dummy1()`, `Dummy2()`... for?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the documentation for the undocumented GAC API: [DOC: Global Assembly Cache (GAC) APIs Are Not Documented in the .NET Framework Software Development Kit (SDK) Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20140520123254/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/317540).

This API is designed to be used from native code, so [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224040605/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/junfeng/archive/2004/09/14/229649.aspx) might help you program it from C#.

If you're after a quick solution, `gacutil /l` works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually people make the assumption that the GAC is located in c:<windir>\assembly, which is 99% true.  So you could write code to iterate through the files found in that folder.

The more orthodox way would be to use the Fusion API, which is COM-based. A managed wrapper is available on this blog site:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/sample-for-using-gac-apis-sample-of-managed-gac-api-wrappers-and-a-test-application-for-managed-gac-api-wrappers)

The site also contains sample managed code showing how to use the Fusion API to enumerate the installed assemblies - the code is pretty much written out for you, so just ctrl+c and then ctrl+v...  :)

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/test-application-for-managed-gac-api-wrappers)

HTH...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for sake of new travellers...

We have a (free) fusion library available for download at http://dilithium.co.za/info/products/gac-api/ which does exactly this. **Disclosure:** Yes, I'm affiliated. No, I won't get money if you download. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can load dotnet exe as and find their dependecy as follows :

```
var applicationExeWithPath ="C:\.......\someapplicaiton.exe" 

var assemblies = Assembly.LoadFile(applicationExeWithPath ).GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

then iterate over those assembly and check if they exist in GAC or not

```
public static class GacUtil
{
    public static bool IsAssemblyInGAC(string assemblyFullName)
    {
        try
        {
            return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assemblyFullName)
                           .GlobalAssemblyCache;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsAssemblyInGAC(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache;
    }
}
```