# Run Console App Despite FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Some of our apps have a dependency on a common dll that is used for logging and configuration. This common dll is added to the GAC on our servers, and isn't included in the bin folder of our deployments.

I want to write a simple console app to check if common.dll has been added to the GAC on the servers.
I have had no luck checking this programatically using fusion or assembly.load: [Check GAC for an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933947/check-gac-for-an-assembly)

My idea was to include a reference to the dll locally, make sure copy local is off and then try catch the FileNotFoundException on the server when a call is made to a method in the dll.

Something like this

```
  static void Main()
        {
            try
            {                 
                Common.Logger.LogInfo("Testing logger."); //call to the dll
                Console.WriteLine("loaded successfully");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Common dll missing!" + e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

But as the dll isn't present the app will crash and throw a FileNotFoundException before even hitting the main method. I assume there is some initial checking that all dlls are present when running the .exe - is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving it into a separate method:

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {     
        CheckLogger();            
        Console.WriteLine("loaded successfully");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Common dll missing!" + e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}  

static void CheckLogger()
{
    Common.Logger.LogInfo("Testing logger."); //call to the dll
}
```

You need the `Main` method to start *running* to enter the `try`/`catch` block and that won't happen if it cannot be (JIT) *compiled*. But as each method is compiled separately, this should work. The `FileNotFoundException` for missing assemblies is fired during compilation of methods that directly depend on the assembly.